# SQL Statement to strip off characters when using a wildcard

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to strip off all characters in a column beginning with CN=WILDCARD, so essentially stripping off whatever follows CN= and ,

Comment: Sample data, expected output.

Comment: research LEFT() and LEN() functions. A combination of the two should do what you are after

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @MyString VARCHAR(255) = 'CN=WILDCARD, Plus some other stuff.'
SELECT LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@MyString, CHARINDEX(',', @MyString)+1, 255))
```

Returns "Plus some other stuff."

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to strip off whatever follows 'CN=' and before ','

here is the query:

```
declare @var varchar(255)='CN=wildcard a b c,some more text';
select SUBSTRING(@var,4, charindex(',',@var)-4)
```

> Output: wildcard a b c